# Identity for a sum of binomial coefficients

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, fractions

I am trying to prove the following identity:

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=0}^{n-m} \frac{n-m\choose i}{n-1 \choose k+i} = \frac{1}{m {m-1 \choose k}},
\end{equation}

where $0 \leq k \leq m-1, 1 \leq m \leq n$, and $k,m,n$ are all integer valued.

It is straightforward to see that this holds for $m=n$, but I don't see how I can generalize this. I have programmed the functions and verified that it indeed holds for any legal combination of $m, n$ and $k$.

A puzzling thing about this identity is that the RHS does not involve $n$ at all. This makes me think that I could rewrite the LHS in some way.

Proving this by induction seems difficult as the summand changes. I have also looked for known identities for binomial coefficients and sums of binomial coefficients, but have not figured out how to apply any of those in this case with a binomial coefficient in the denominator. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Identities_involving_binomial_coefficients)

Any ideas?

Comment: Just saying, this would always work: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ZeilbergersAlgorithm.html I can also recommend the book https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$
\eqalign{
  & {1 \over {n\left( \matrix{  n - 1 \cr   q + k \cr}  \right)}}
 = {{\Gamma \left( {q + k + 1} \right)\Gamma \left( {n - q - k} \right)} \over {n\Gamma \left( n \right)}} =   \cr 
  &  = {\rm B}\left( {q + k + 1,n - q - k} \right)
 = \int_{t = 0}^1 {t^{\,q + k} \left( {1 - t} \right)^{n - \,q - k - 1} dt}  =   \cr 
  &  = \int_{t = 0}^1 {t^{\,q} \left( {1 - t} \right)^{m - \,q - 1} t^{\,k} \left( {1 - t} \right)^{n - m\, - k} dt} \quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\,\,}
 {\left( \matrix{  n - m \cr   k \cr}  \right){\rm B}\left( {q + k + 1,n - q - k} \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  =  \cdots  \cr} 
$$